# Error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular

I am working with angular 2 and I have a weird error :

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type
```

I command line it appears this :

```
[0] app/category-details.component.ts(40,39): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ CategoryID: number; }'.
[0]   Property 'CategoryID' is missing in type 'Object'.
[0] app/category-details.component.ts(45,39): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ CategoryID: number; }'.
```

This is the code :

```
export class CategoryDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public category: Object;

    private view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
    private skip: number = 0;

    constructor(private service: ProductsService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.view = this.service;

        this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip: this.skip, take: 5 });
    }

    protected pageChange({ skip, take }: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.skip = skip;
        this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip, take });
    }
}
```

It shows me this errors at lines :

```
this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip: this.skip, take: 5 });

this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip, take });
```

How can I solve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service method `this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip, take });` expects first argument to be of type `{ CategoryID: number; }`, while you are passing `this.category` which is annotated as a `Object`.
You can create an interface for category so both `queryForCategory`  and `@Input() public category: ICategory;` are using it.

```
// interface.ts
export interface ICategory {
    CategoryID: number;
}

// service declaration
queryForCategory(category: ICategory, options)


// input property annotation
 @Input() public category: ICategory;
```